# Use of v4 content Loader

Tags: java, android, socket.io

These days I am experimenting with Socket.IO implementation in Android Java. I have found one sample on Google which is 2 years older. After viewing his source code I have seen that he has used `android.support.v4.content.Loader<D>` and the reason he documented is:

> we are using a Loader to manage the socket to make it persisted across Activity instances that happen when rotating.

**My first question is I don't understand this statement. Does it means that it will create different activity instances when device is rotated? Is this correct?**

In Android documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html) it is mentioned:

> Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0. When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation.

Again unclear... :(

He has connected socketed in `Loader`'s `onForceLoad()` and disconnected it in `onReset()` methods.

**My other question is, should I use it or is there any alternative and better approach to it (since its 2 years old)?**

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#loaders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On rotation (and some other events) the activity gets destroyed and re-created. That's how Android works.
- The other thing just says that it if you put v4.loader in your code, it will use v4, even if running on a newer device. Nothing to worry here.
- Yes that is 2 years old. Loader was created to try to solve one problem and just created more. I don't recommend anyone to ever using it.

If you need your socket in just 1 activity, what I recommend is the ViewModel from the Architecture components.

For that you add this dependency to your gradle file:

```
 implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

then create your ViewModel to hold the socket:

```
public class SocketViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public SocketViewModel(Application app) {
       // add here code to start/open/initialise the socket
    }

    @Override public void onCleared() {
       // add here code to close/finialse the socket
    }

    // create a get() or some other method to interface your Activity to your socket code

}
```

finally on your Activity you call this to get the ViewModel:

```
private SocketViewModel socketModel;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstance);
     ... your view init ...

     socketModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SocketViewModel.class);
}
```

and this will make your socket survive rotation without issues.

Comment: Very well explained... Thanks a lot. Btw. what do you suggest if I want to share the socket between more than 1 activity?

Comment: Than it's a bit more complicated. You'll have to use a Singleton that detects activities. This code here https://github.com/sensorberg-dev/EasyIPC/blob/master/foregrounddetector/src/main/java/com/sensorberg/easyipc/foregrounddetector/ForegroundDetector.java is a good start. It's meant to detect if any of your activities are in foreground. To be just a few, you'll have to do changes to instead use `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` for the activities to call a `register/unregister` during `onStart/onStop`

Answer (score 0):

1. By default configuration change will trigger activity recreation so if your socket connection cannot survive it it will be reconnected/created again. Loaders survive activity recreation so if you want your socket connection to be stable you can use loaders/retain fragments/disable activity recreation and etc.
2. Loaders where added in Android 3.0, so to make it work on older versions of android its implementation where added to support library
3. It's up to you what to use. As I said, You can use Loaders/Bound services/Retain Fragments/Classes that don't care about lifecycle...